# Reading Active Directory Logs

Tags: active-directory, event-log

I am working on a Data Analytics project. In this project i have to read logs from Active Directory and then need to do further processing on that logs.

I have to insert that logs into a **Kafka Topic.** 
Now i am not able to understand that how can i get logs from active directory? is there any connector for it? I gone through below link but not able to understand anything with this -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wec/windows-event-collector
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wec/windows-event-collector

If anyone has any link related to it then it will be really helpful to me.

Comment: Is my answer what you need?

Comment: @TonyJu Thanks for your answer. I will check and let you know if it solves my issue. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Directory has report feature.

**Audit logs** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs

**Sign in logs** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins

**Risk sign-ins** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-risky-sign-ins

**Risk events** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-risk-events

**users at risk** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-user-at-risk

You can use [report api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-reporting-api) to get the logs. You can also [archive azure ad logs to an Azure storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/quickstart-azure-monitor-route-logs-to-storage-account).

Comment: do you have any idea how Securonix is doing it . see their website - https://www.securonix.com/platforms/snypr/               and see "Connector Library and Real-Time Data Enrichment" section.

Comment: https://www.securonix.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/x2b-1.png.pagespeed.ic.LmZsMiqOFw.webp

Comment: I am afraid there is no such connector in azure ad, but you can use the report api to archive logs.

Comment: @Vinitkumar If my answer is helpful for you, please make it as answer. Thank you. 
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the logs related to Active Directory in the Event Viewer, or if you want to get the file location where logs are actually stored, so you can get these file in [C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs] directory.